# JAVA: Execute external program which are packaged in a jar file

Tags: java

I have a jar file, in which there is a external program inside it. 
That means in the jar's implementation, it puts the external program into its resources folder, and there is a function call the program using Process class.
I am using the jar and try to call this function which encapsulates the program. But got below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "file:/C:/Data/Work/workspace/keytool/lib/baseutil-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/decode.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

Your help are great appreciated.

EDIT:

the method calling the file in the jar:

```
public String retrive(String dmidecode) throws Exception {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(dmidecode, "-s", options[i]).start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line;
    sb.append(options[i]);
    sb.append("=");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    sb.append("\n");
}
return sb.toString();
```

}

Comment: You mean to say the jar contain external library ?

Comment: yes, the jar contains an external program file.

Comment: The external jar is in the classpath ??

Comment: Yes. the external jar is in the classpath.

Comment: can you show me ur MANIFEST.INF

Comment: `it puts the external program into its resources folder` seems you still tries to execute the file from the jar. Show the code where you are using `Process`.

Comment: The method calling the file in the jar:
    public String retrive(String dmidecode) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            Process process = new ProcessBuilder(dmidecode, "-s", options[i]).start();
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

Comment: @PeterMmm , can I execute the file from the jar? If yes, How?

Comment: No, in Windows you cannot run a program from a jar (zip) file. The program must exist in the file system.